# JavaScript unixtime problem

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I get the time from the database in Unix format.

It looks like this: console.log (time);
Result: 1300709088000

Now I want to reformat it and pick out only the time, I found this: [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

That did not work as I want. The time I get is this:

```
1300709088000
9:0:0

1300709252000
6:33:20

1300709316000
0:20:0

1300709358000
12:0:0

1300709530000
11:46:40
```

It is very wrong times when I know that times are quite different. How can I fix it?

```
    console.log(time);

var date = new Date(time*1000);
// hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();
// minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
// seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

// will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
console.log(formattedTime);
```

Comment: You haven't shown how the value gets from the database to your Javascript context, and what transformations is experiences along the way.

Answer (score 3):

> It looks like this: console.log (time); Result: 1300709088000

That doesn't look like a Unix timestamp (seconds since The Epoch), it looks like *milliseconds* since The Epoch. So you wouldn't multiply by 1000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds for JavaScript, it's already in milliseconds (or you're dealing with dates more than 41,000 years from now; which is fair enough).

Test:

```
var times = [
    1300709088000,
    1300709252000,
    1300709316000,
    1300709358000,
    1300709530000
  ];
var index;

for (index = 0; index < times.length; ++index) {
    display(times[index] + " => " + new Date(times[index]));
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/emazo3)

---

**Update**: Or getting the individual parts:

```
var times = [
    1300709088000,
    1300709252000,
    1300709316000,
    1300709358000,
    1300709530000
  ];
var index, dt;

for (index = 0; index < times.length; ++index) {
    dt = new Date(times[index]);
    display(times[index] +
            " => " +
            dt +
            " (" + formatISOLikeDate(dt) + ")");
}

// Not all implementations have ISO-8601 stuff yet, do it manually
function formatISOLikeDate(dt) {
    var day    = String(dt.getDate()),
        month  = String(dt.getMonth() + 1), // Starts at 0
        year   = String(dt.getFullYear()),
        hour   = String(dt.getHours()),
        minute = String(dt.getMinutes()),
        second = String(dt.getSeconds());

    return zeroPad(year, 4) + "-" +
           zeroPad(month, 2) + "-" +
           zeroPad(day, 2) + " " +
           zeroPad(hour, 2) + ":" +
           zeroPad(minute, 2) + ":" +
           zeroPad(second, 2);
}
function zeroPad(str, width) {
    while (str.length < width) {
        str = "0" + str;
    }
    return str;
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/emazo3/3) ...but if you're going to be doing much of anything with dates, I'd look at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your time stamps are **not** in Unix format, they're already in the Javascript *millisecond* resolution format.

Hence you shouldn't be multiplying by 1000 when you create your `Date` object.

Comment: I've tried to do something like this:

   console.log (time);

     where date = new Date (time);
     / / hours party from the timestamp
     was hours = date.getHours ();
     / / party minutes from the timestamp
     Every minute = date.getMinutes ();
     / / Seconds Party From The timestamp
     where seconds = date.getSeconds ();

     / / Will display time up 10:30:23 format
     was formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
     console.log (formattedTime);

The result is this:
1300709088000
NaN: NaN: NaN

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do something like this:

console.log (time);

```
 where date = new Date (time);
 / / hours party from the timestamp
 was hours = date.getHours ();
 / / party minutes from the timestamp
 Every minute = date.getMinutes ();
 / / Seconds Party From The timestamp
 where seconds = date.getSeconds ();

 / / Will display time up 10:30:23 format
 was formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
 console.log (formattedTime);
```

The result is this:
1300709088000
NaN: NaN: NaN

Comment: Why is this posted as an answer?

Comment: get rid of 'where', 'was' and 'every' and replace with 'var' and it might just work...